# How to get octal chmod format from stat() in c

Tags: c

I need to know how to get file permissions in octal format and save it to an int. I tried something like this:

```
struct stat buf;  
stat(filename, &buf);
int statchmod = buf.st_mode;
printf("chmod: %i\n", statchmod);
```

But he output was:

```
chmod: 33279
```

and should be 777.

Comment: A very quick and simple search would have found you a reference page, like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) where you can see all format codes. Even easier would have been to use the command `man printf`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

33279 is the decimal representation of the octal 100777. You get a decimal representation because you requested the number to be printed as a decimal, through the format identifier `%i`. `%o` will print it as an octal number.

However, st_mode will get you a whole lot more information. (Hence the `100` at the start.) You'll want to use the `S_IRWXU` (rwx information of the "user"), `S_IRWXG` (group) and `S_IRWXO` (other) constants to get the permissions for the owner, group and other figured out. These are respectively defined at 700, 070 and 007, all in octal representation. OR'ing these together and filtering out the specified bits using AND will yield you only the data you want.

The final program hence becomes something like this:

```
struct stat buf;  
stat(filename, &buf);
int statchmod = buf.st_mode & (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
printf("chmod: %o\n", statchmod);
```

Resources:

1. [More about format identifiers](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html)
2. [Related constants](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need chmod to compare one input, the input will be int "777" and search for files that have chmod 777.How to compare these two variables when the input is decimal while it is octal representation of chmod  are looking for?

Comment: You can use octal values in C by simply prepending a value with 0. For example, 0777. You can then simply test for equality `if (statchmod == 0777) { ... }`

Comment: @user1827257 Decimal and octal are just relevant for string representations. Internally, the value is stored in whatever format the hardware uses [binary, unless something very odd happened]. To see whether the ugo permissions are 777, just check `(statchmod & 0777) == 0777`.

Comment: Now I understand, just one more question, how to make it, when "777" is a variable of type int (decimal), so as to achieve the variable is an octal number in the comparisons? for example: `if (statchmod == mychmodint) { ... }` ?

Comment: Like @DanielFischer said, octal and decimal are just representations. You can safely assign an octal representation to an integer; `int mychmodint = 0777;`

If, for some reason, you *must* work with an integer with decimal representation 777, you'll have to convert it.

Let's say:
    int mydecimal = 777;
    int myoctal = ((mydecimal / 100) << 6) | ((mydecimal%100 / 10) << 3) | (mydecimal % 10);
    // myoctal is now 0777

However, just having mychmodint = 0777 will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please upvote or mark this answer as accepted. If not, you should either add whatever you ended up doing as your own answer or edit your question so it's clear what you are asking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I like [@ilias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14325854/105539) answer. However, if you're like me and actually want the full chmod value (such as for saving and restoring original file permissions completely), then this routine would do it, and would ensure leading zeroes are not lopped off either.

```
static std::string getChmodPerms(std::string sFile) {
    struct stat buf;
    stat(sFile.c_str(),&buf);
    int statchmod = buf.st_mode;
    char mybuff[50];
    sprintf(mybuff,"%#o",statchmod);
    std::string sResult(mybuff);
    return sResult;
}
```

It's C++, but it's trivial to convert to C if you want.