# How to get octal chmod from st_mode

Tags: c

Hi I have a similar question to this post [How to get octal chmod format from stat() in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325706/how-to-get-octal-chmod-format-from-stat-in-c) but I dont have any reputation so I cant comment on it. I was wondering what value would statchmod get if the file had permission drwxrw-r-- and is that value in decimal or octal?

```
struct stat buf; 
stat(filename, &buf); 
int statchmod = buf.st_mode;
```

I was also wondering what number

```
statchmod & 0777
```

outputs and again is it in decimal or octal? Should it output 0764?

EDIT: Thanks, I think I have a better understanding now. Still not clear on statchmod though. Is it in bits So would

```
statchmod & 511
```

output 500?

Comment: Octal, decimal, etc. is about how a number is *represented*, especially for display, not about its actual value.  Thus, it does not make much sense to ask whether the value of a variable is in decimal or octal, and how it is presented on output depends on how you output it.

Comment: With that said, yes, the octal representation of the symbolic directory mode you presented is indeed 764.  To express that as an octal literal in C source code you must preceded it with a leading zero: `0764`.  Masking that value with bitmask `0777` will not change it.